# PHP IF statement not reacting how I think it should?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am having a little trouble with the following php statement:

```
if (!userIsLoggedIn()) {
    $prPrice = (empty($prPrice2)) ? $prPrice1 : $prPrice1;
} else {
    $prPrice = (empty($prPrice2)) ? $prPrice1 : $prPrice2;
}
```

Here is an example of two products:

```
product 1 -> price1 = 1.00
product 1 -> price2 = 0.00
product 2 -> price1 = 1.00
product 2 -> price2 = 0.80
```

If a user is not logged into our website (userIsLoggedIn function) Then they should only be able to see the product price1, regardless if product price2 exists or not.

On the other hand, When a user has logged into our website. Then they should be able to see price2 for products where it exists, or they will simply see price1.

Now the problem with me code, is this:

A user is not logged on, they see price1 regardless of whether an item has a price2 set or not.

When a user has logged in, they see price2 for items that have a price two, but this is the strange part, for items that do not have a price2, it simply displays **0**, Where it should display price1.

Does anyone have any input as to why the mentioned code is producing this effect?

I can provide further code relating to the userIsLoggedIn function, on request.

Thank you to anyone that would like to help!!

Comment: I believe your second line can be shortened to `$prPrice = $prPrice1;`

Comment: @Zach Good point, thank you. I guess I got a bit carried away with that.

Comment: How is `$prPrice2` being set?

Comment: $prPrice = ($prPrice2 != 0 && userIsLoggedIn()) ? $prPrice2 : $prPrice1. That should be even shorter.

Comment: @Tieson It is a field stored in a table within a mysql database. each row has 5 fields, id, desc, price1, price2, cost

Comment: @Dan Thank you, I will work on that. But it needs to check empty, not isset.

Comment: @Dan okay, it does not need to check empty, as your code produces the same effect as mine, but with the same problem too.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Can you also verify that the variables have the values as you state above not only in the database but also in the php script?

Comment: @BlackberryFan But how is the PHP variable being populated prior to the value check? If it's not initialized properly, it could theoretically have a non-empty value... regardless, Dan's comment above should work much better.

Comment: @Dan The code is pages long, Which parts do you need to put together a bigger picture?

Comment: Well it would suffice to put a var_dump of price1 and price2 before the if to verify if the values are what you expect them to be, because if they are the code you posted should be working fine.

Comment: @Dan You are my hero o my god!!! It has been 2 days now and as I was posting some more code, I saw the reason for this error. A while loop was being started when checked against the wrong variable. Basically, 2 data queries. Now I was not very clever, and went and named these two queries result and result1. So the loop was displaying data from the wrong query. Please post a solution and I shall choose it as my answer because you provided me with the inspiration to look deeper :) Plus my code looks real neat now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. You could verify that the variables hold the value you expect by using `var_dump()`.

Also your code might be shortened like this. However if you have to check a lot of prices it's probably not adviseable to execute userIsLoggedIn() in each check but instead save that result in a variable.

`$prPrice = ($prPrice2 != 0 && userIsLoggedIn()) ? $prPrice2 : $prPrice1;`

Comment: Thank you, you are the man! In anycase, what would you suggest as a better solution to dealing with the fact that the function is being executed +- 50-100 times each search?

Comment: Just put it before the loop that goes through the results. Example: `$userIsLoggedIn = userIsLoggedIn();` then use $userIsLoggedIn instead as it should hold true or false as if the function was executed each time.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working as it should - price2 for your product 1 should not return `true` on a call to `empty()` because it has a value of 0.00.  Maybe you should check if a value is 0 or not instead?

Comment: There are over 3000 products, all with the price1 field set accordingly. It displays when a user is not logged into the system, but when the user is logged in, they all display as 0, unless there is a price2 that is not empty, then it displays the price2. Can you think of any other reason behind this?

Comment: I think you might be getting meanings of 'empty' confused.  If a value in a database, where the column type is a number format, is `null` (i.e. empty), this doesn't equate to a call to `empty()` in PHP returning `true`.  I assume this is the reason why your product 1 price2 is 0.00, where you think it is null.

Comment: The field price2 in the database, is always either 0.00 or anything higher than that. The field price1 is always set. I am a bit confused at what you are implying :/

Comment: Well, ok, what do you think `empty($prPrice2)` is checking? Try `$prPrice2 == 0` instead